# Console error with Autodesk Forge Visor Cookie

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-bim360

I have my application in NodeJs, I have followed the steps in the tutorial and now I am progressing.
In FireFox I get a Cookie error. This is the message in the console:

The cookie "viewer-version-in-cookie" will soon be rejected because it is external and does not have the "Partitioned" attribute.

Is there any solution?

How can I manage this cookie so that the app is not blocked?

Comment: Could you please share more details about your case? What tutorial exactly are you following? I don't think the `viewer-version-in-cookie` cookie is coming from the viewer.